# In React useEffect doesn't update after the value has changed from other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to do some kind of online shop for myself and I got a problem.
I want to render my shopping cart size in the `NavBar` component (which is on every page).

I created a Cart Items service where I put all my added items, and it also has functions to `addItem`, `removeItem`, `getCart`, `getCartSize`.

When I click on Add/Remove on specific product, I would like to do that the value on `NavBar` with cart size would be changing depending on the cart size (from `getCartSize` method). I already tried to use `useEffect` hook, but it does not recognize when the value of `cartSize` is changed, how can I do that?

This is what I have done already.

`navbar.jsx`:

```
//...
//...
import {getTotalCount} from '../../services/myCart';

export default function Navbar() {
  // ...
  const [count, setCount] = useState();  

  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(getTotalCount());
    console.log('counto useeffect');
  },[getTotalCount()]);
  //},[getTotalCount]); doesn'work also.
  //},[count]); doesn'work also.

  return (
    <>
        <header className="navbar">
                <Link className="navbar__list-item__home-icon" to="/"><span><FaHome/></span></Link>
                <Link className="navbar__list-item" to="/products">Products</Link>            
                <h2>cart size--> {count}</h2>
                <Link className="navbar__list-item__cart-img" to="shopping-cart"><span><FaShoppingCart/></span></Link>   
        </header>
    </>
  );
}
```

`myCart.js` all functions work fine and I call them when I click add/remove button in on my component in the products page.

```
var InTheCart = [

];
var totalCount = 0;

export function AddToCart(item) {
    // ... logic
    totalCount++;
}

export function ContainsInTheCart(id) {
    return InTheCart.findIndex(x=> x.item.id == id) != -1 ? true: false;   
}

export function RemoveFromCart(id) {
   // ... logic
        totalCount--;
}

export function getCart() {
    return InTheCart;
}

export function getTotalCount() {
    return totalCount;
}
```

Comment: //},[count]) will cause infinit loop beacuse every time useState happens the rerender will be called

Comment: so the initial value is 0 ? I mean the getTotalFunction always return 0. is it right ?

Comment: yes in myCart.js as you can see totalCount is 0, at the beginning

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In React useEffect does not update after the value has changed from other component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59198761/in-react-useeffect-does-not-update-after-the-value-has-changed-from-other-compon)

Answer (score 1):

React is called react because it re-renders when it *reacts* to something that changed.

For that to happen, the react components need to know, somehow, that something changed.

In the code example you show, the `totalCount` (which global access provided by exported function `getTotalCount`) is independent from react component tree, so that data can change without react knowing it.

So, the question is: how to make your react component aware of those changes?

A few mechanisms exist, here are a few of them:

1. Use a global state manager like redux, with redux actions and reducer to mutate the state and `useSelector` in the component that will make them aware of any change, and rerender
2. React context which will hold the cart state. That context can export both that data, and th function that will mutate the data, so they can be shared between components that have access to that context provider.

Your context could be used in the component that way:

```js
  const cartContext = useContext(CartContext)
  const { cartState, addToCart, removeFromCart } = cartContext
  const { totalCount, inTheCart } = cartState

  [...somwhere later...]
  <ul><li onClick={() => removeFromCart(index)}>{inTheCart[index].name}</li></ul>
  <footer>{`${totalCount} items`}</footer>
```

I let you build the context object around your existing functions ;)

Comment: Okay, I will try to redo it with redux

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to lift the state up. Create the state in your layout file from where `Header` and `Cart` can access the `count` as `Props`. `useEffect` will be invoked whenever there is a change in the `state` or `props` of a component.

Comment: That would work if all myCart.js stuff is done with useState API in that component. In that case NavBar will not need any effect , they can just use the totalCount prop. It will rerender whenever that changes. Limitation is that if another component need that state, it must be a direct child of that parent component. Or, in case of a lot of intermediary components, you need to "drill" those props everywhere. Still a good solution for simple use case.

Comment: Yes you are right. It all depends on your scenario. If want to access the count at multiple places and want to get rid of drilling the props then using `Context API` or `Redux` will be a good option.