# useEffect does not update after the value has changed from other component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to do some kind of online shop for myself and I got a problem.
I want to render my shopping cart size in the `NavBar` component (which is on every page).

I created a Cart Items service where I put all my added items, and it also has functions to `addItem`, `removeItem`, `getCart`, `getCartSize`.

When I click on Add/Remove on specific product, I would like to do that the value on `NavBar` with cart size would be changing depending on the cart size (from `getCartSize` method). I already tried to use `useEffect` hook, but it does not recognize when the value of `cartSize` is changed, how can I do that?

This is what I have done already.

`navbar.jsx`:

```
//...
//...
import {getTotalCount} from '../../services/myCart';

export default function Navbar() {
  // ...
  const [count, setCount] = useState();  

  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(getTotalCount());
    console.log('counto useeffect');
  },[getTotalCount()]);


  return (
    <>
        <header className="navbar">
                <Link className="navbar__list-item__home-icon" to="/"><span><FaHome/></span></Link>
                <Link className="navbar__list-item" to="/products">Products</Link>            
                <h2>cart size--> {count}</h2>
                <Link className="navbar__list-item__cart-img" to="shopping-cart"><span><FaShoppingCart/></span></Link>   
        </header>
    </>
  );
}
```

`myCart.js` all functions work fine and I call them when I click add/remove button in on my component in the products page.

```
var InTheCart = [

];
var totalCount = 0;

export function AddToCart(item) {
    // ... logic
    totalCount++;
}

export function ContainsInTheCart(id) {
    return InTheCart.findIndex(x=> x.item.id == id) != -1 ? true: false;   
}

export function RemoveFromCart(id) {
   // ... logic
        totalCount--;
}

export function getCart() {
    return InTheCart;
}

export function getTotalCount() {
    return totalCount;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bad example of state management!! Basically you're trying to access shared state between components, and what you should do is to use a state management approach (lift up state, use a library like redux - mobx, use hook context,...). Instead of export variables and functions from a js file (myCard.js), create a CardStore/CardContext file,...etc is the way to "state-manage" that shared state

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In React useEffect does not update after the value has changed from other component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59198761/in-react-useeffect-does-not-update-after-the-value-has-changed-from-other-compon)